# Unable to get POST data in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Hello guys im trying to get form data t be able to use it on the server, im using nodejs with express and im trying to console.log the data from a form, when the form gets submitted it also redirects to another page via the html code.

Here is my app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static('files'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile('views/index.html', {root: __dirname })
});

app.get('/mercancia', (req, res)=> {
   res.sendFile('files/merch.html', {root: __dirname })
});

app.get('/datos', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile('files/Direccion.html', {root: __dirname })
});

app.post('/submit_data', (req, res)=> {
        const postBody = req.body;

        console.log(postBody);
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/')
});


app.listen(3000, console.log('App Listening to port 3000'));
```

And here is my html form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>direccion</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "form.css" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"  type="image/x-icon"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>Agrega tu direccion</h2>
                </div>

                <form id="form" class="form" method="POST" action="/submit_data">
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="Nombre">Nombre Completo</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Jose Luis Licea Alcaraz" id="nombre" name="nombre">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error message</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="Direccion">Direccion </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Calle, Numero, Colonia" id="direccion" name="direccion">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error message</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="CodigoPostal">Codigo Postal </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="64860" id="cp" name="cp">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error message</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="Telefono">Telefono </label>
                        <input type="tel" placeholder="+528112551388" id="tel" name="telefono">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error message</small>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="Pais">Pais </label>
                        <select name="pais"  id="pais" name="pais">
                            <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="chile">Chile</option>
                            <option value="argentina">Argentina</option>
                            <option value="guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                            <option value="salvador">El Salvador</option>
                             <option value="santoDomingo">Santo Domingo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>Escoge tu prenda</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="Prenda">Prenda </label>
                        <select name="prenda"  id="prenda" name="prenda "onchange="changeImage();">
                            <option value="hoodie_roja">Sudadera Roja</option>
                            <option value="Hoodie Negra">Sudadera Negra</option>
                            <option value="Playera">Playera</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="img_direccion">
                        <img id="img_prenda" src="hoddie jeil0 R.png" alt="Prenda" width=250 height=250>
                    </div>

                    <div class="button_paypal">
                        <a target="_blank" href="https://paypal.me/AlcarazLicea?locale.x=es_XC">
                            <button type = "submit" name="paypal" value="image_paypal">
                                <img src="paypal.png" alt="Check out with PayPal" height="100%" width="80%"/>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <footer>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/gaming/Jeil0188">
            <img src="facebookGaming.png" width=40 height="40">
           </a>

        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Jeil0188">
            <img src="facebookLogo.png" width=40 height="40">
           </a>

        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.twitch.tv/jl0188">
            <img src="twitch_invertido.png" width=40 height="40">
           </a>

           <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/jeil0188/">
            <img src="instagramlogo_invertido.png" width=40 height="40">
           </a>

        <div class="footerContainer">
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="logic.js"></script>
</html>
```

i dont get anything with my console log, what am i doing wrong?

Please help me i dont get any output out of the console.log

Comment: There is no problem in your express code. Try debug your front end. Make sure a request is sent from your front end

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Try Hoang Trung's suggestion in the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thanks to everyone that helped me.

The issue was in the frontend, on my logic.js file i had on my submit function for the button the function: e.preventDefault(); which prevented the form from being submitted, i comment it and created a redirect via express for the  href link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it because the `a` tag takes a click instead of `button`. You should remove the `a` tag and write a click function for the button to open a new page.